# Understanding Android FPS

Tags: android, loops

I have a simple gameloop that looks like this...

```
// ROUGHLY 30 FPS
final int TARGET_MILLIS_PER_FRAME = 33;
long tickStart;
long tickEnd;
long totalTickTime;
long previousTickTime;

@Override
public void run() {

    running = true;

    // GameLoop
    while (running) {
        tickStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        canvas = null;
        try {
            // Lock canvas for editing
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                gameView.updateGame();
                gameView.drawGame(canvas);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                tickEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
                totalTickTime = tickEnd - tickStart;
                Log.d(TAG, "Total milliseconds to update and render game " + (totalTickTime));
                Log.d(TAG, "FPS:  " + (1000 / totalTickTime));
                Log.d(TAG, "Previous tick time: " + (previousTickTime));
                Log.d(TAG, "Average of 2 tick times: " + ((previousTickTime + totalTickTime) / 2));
                if (totalTickTime < TARGET_MILLIS_PER_FRAME) {
                    long sleepTime = TARGET_MILLIS_PER_FRAME - totalTickTime;
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "sleeping for  " + (sleepTime));

                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                previousTickTime = totalTickTime;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

When I run my game, the following is logged...

```
05-08 13:39:03.439: D/GameLoop(363): Total milliseconds to update and render game 12
05-08 13:39:03.439: D/GameLoop(363): FPS:  83
05-08 13:39:03.439: D/GameLoop(363): Previous tick time: 11
05-08 13:39:03.439: D/GameLoop(363): Average of 2 tick times: 11
05-08 13:39:03.439: D/GameLoop(363): sleeping for  8
```

Notice the extremely high FPS, if I remove the sleep, can my game actually rendering this quickly?

Comment: I think you should add the `lock` and `unlock` operations in the time measurement, so all the loop time is taken into consideration.

Comment: Nice observation, not sure how I didn't think of that before. Original code has been edited to reflect that suggestion as well as the new logs. However, FPS is still a bit high, is my device actually capable of rendering this fast?

Comment: that really depends on what's inside `gameView.drawGame`, but according to your observations I don't see why not.

Comment: **"...is my device actually capable of rendering this fast?"** : I don't understand why you are asking that. You're getting a 12ms difference between `tickStart` and `tickEnd` - the math speaks for itself.

Comment: well I know for IOS max FPS = 60, so was curious about android as well, is there some underlying software limitation to physical renders in a given amount of time?

Comment: As @njzk2 it depends on what your `drawGame` method does. Why are you concerned by FPS? Normally you would only redraw something if it has changed - the concept of FPS implies it's constantly changing.

Comment: there is a difference between how fast you will draw on the canvas and how often it will be pushed to the screen. The drawn FPS may differ from the displayed FPS, which can be limited by the OS.

Comment: @njzk2 I'm concerned about FPS as I am trying to figure out why my sprites move faster on 1 device vs. another.

Comment: there is something weird in your log. total says 12ms, target is 33, yet sleep time is only 8 ? that comes up to 20, not 33